# Como compilar um arquivo PHP?

Tags: php, bytecode

Existe alguma forma de transformar arquivo PHP em `bytecode` ou algo similar, e depois executá-lo de forma nativa? Preciso que alguns arquivos em um sistema fiquem pré-compilados por conta de performance em alguns casos,  e "segurança" contra olhares curiosos em outros.

Pesquisando, encontrei os arquivos `PHAR`, mas não descobri se eles são puramente um pacote descompilável como um `.jar`, ou se são `bytecode`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## TL;DR

Uma técnica simplista que você pode usar para se proteger "contra olhares curiosos" e ter um tipo básico (baixo) de "segurança" é ***ofuscar*** o código.

É possível obter uma segurança mais elevada com ofuscadores de *bytecode*, entretanto as ferramentas disponíveis (que eu conheço) são pagas e exigem a instalação de extensões no PHP, o que não seria possível em hospedagens compartilhadas, por exemplo.

## Motivação

Particularmente, há vários anos eu usava uma técnica simples de ofuscação quando desenvolvi um CMS (*Content Management System*) próprio que era instalado em sites de vários clientes, ou seja, hospedagens que estavam em poder dos mesmos. Isso foi na época em que a extensão PHAR ainda era experimental.

Meu objetivo com a ofuscação era evitar que um "sobrinho" qualquer (pseudo-webdesigner) que soubesse usar cliente de FTP começasse a fuçar no sistema, tentar copiar para outro site, etc. Na verdade, já ocorreu de um cliente curioso, dado a entendido, bisbilhotar o fonte para tentar burlar certas validações. Então, era um tipo de "segurança *for dummies*".

## Implementação Simplista

Eu sabia que a "segurança" obtida via ofuscação era apenas contra bisbilhoteiros sem capacitação em programação, então usei uma técnica muito simples.

Primeiro instalei o [Phing](http://www.phing.info/), uma espécie de Ant para PHP, de forma que eu pude automatizar o processo de ofuscação.

Depois eu criei uma *task* onde, para cada arquivo:

1. Usava o método [`php_strip_whitespace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php) para limpar o código-fonte.
2. Codificava o conteúdo em base 64 e colocava-o numa String.
3. O resultado era colocado em um novo arquivo numa estrutura de pastas paralela, que usava um `eval` para conseguir executar o código.

O código era muito parecido com este, que achei no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php):

```php
<?php
$infile=$_SERVER['argv'][4];
$outfile=$_SERVER['argv'][5];
if (!$infile || !$outfile) {
    die("Usage: php {$_SERVER['argv'][0]} <input file> <output file>\n");
}
echo "Processing $infile to $outfile\n";
$data="ob_end_clean();?>";
$data.=php_strip_whitespace($infile);
// compress data
$data=gzcompress($data,9);
// encode in base64
$data=base64_encode($data);
// generate output text
$out='<?ob_start();$a=\''.$data.'\';eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode($a)));$v=ob_get_contents();ob_end_clean();?>';
// write output text
file_put_contents($outfile,$out);
```

A maior diferença é que originalmente eu não capturava a saída numa variável nem usava compressão.

Note que essa é uma abordagem extremamente simplista. Por exemplo, essa técnica não leva em consideração o desempenho. No exemplo pessoal que citei não houve impacto perceptível, mas se houver volume de acessos e/ou uma quantidade razoável de arquivos essa deve ser uma preocupação. Além disso, é fácil para um desenvolvedor descompilar o código original.

## Soluções de "mercado"

Ao invés de reinventar a roda, existem algumas ferramentas que você pode usar para fazer a ofuscação. Na verdade, algumas chegam a armazenar e ofuscar o *bytecode*, o que vai de encontro com a parte da pergunta que se refere ao desempenho.

Note que não tenho experiência com essas ferramentas, já que elas nem existiam quando eu precisei. Porém, sugiro que faça alguns testes e verifique por si mesmo, tentando reverter a ofuscação, se você é capaz de fazê-lo e com qual dificuldade. Além disso, calcule a diferença no tempo de uma solicitação ao usar um código "normal" e um código "compilado" ou ofuscado.

### [POBS](https://github.com/Eccenux/POBS)

Um ofuscador de código livre que, além de ofuscar o código em geral, altera nomes de funções e variáveis de modo a dificultar a leitura mesmo que se consiga fazer a engenharia reversa.

### [PHP Protect](http://www.phpprotect.info/obfuscation.php)

Uma ferramenta gratuita que processa todos os scripts em uma pasta. Provavelmente usa uma técnica simples de ofuscação.

### [Thicket Obfuscator for PHP](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PHPObfuscator.jsp?Home=PHPTools)

Ferramenta paga. Diz usar uma técnica diferente para melhorar o desempenho do script ofuscado.

### [IonCube PHP Encoder](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php)

Ferramenta paga que possibilita armazenar o *bytecode*, criptografá-lo, ofuscá-lo, acrescentar um tempo de expiração, restringir o uso a um MAC Address, etc. Ela já possui uma *task* Phing chamada [`IoncubeEncoderTask`](http://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlhtml/index.html#IoncubeEncoderTask) para processar os arquivos automaticamente.

Esta é uma das ferramentas mais completas da categoria. Entretanto, para execução dos arquivos codificados, é necessário instalar uma extensão no PHP. Logo essa solução é inviável para *shared hosts*.

### [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)

Ferramenta paga da Zend (empresa que desenvolve o PHP) que permite ofuscar o código e proteger a execução do script de diversas formas (semelhante ao descrito anteriormente no IconCube).

## Considerações

Nenhuma proteção garante 100% de segurança. Mesmo as melhores soluções pagas apresentadas acima não são 100% seguras. O site [zendecode.com](http://zendecode.com/), por exemplo, afirma descompilar instantaneamente código do Zend Guard e IconCube.

Enfim, em minha opinião, a melhor proteção não está no código, mas em oferecer serviços com qualidade e excelência. Afinal, para nossa felicidade ou infelicidade, não existem muitos fornecedores de software bons por aí e copiar seu código (a não ser que este contenha alguma informação sigilosa) não vai dar muitas vantagens competitivas para possíveis concorrentes.

Comment: O link do POBS está quebrado, eu achei no GitHub mas não sei se é o mesmo que havia referenciado. https://github.com/Eccenux/POBS

Answer (score 7):

Não, `phar` não é bytecode, entenda o que pode ser feito baseado na necessidade:

## DIstribuição Facilitada

#### phar

É na verdade um pacote contendo os arquivos, não é de fato compilado ou bytecode, foi desenvolvido para ajudar a distribuição de sistemas.

## Performance

#### APC

Extensão do PHP que pode pré compilar arquivos PHP no `cache bytecode`, veja mais [na documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-compile-file.php)

#### HHVM

Projeto opensource iniciado pela Facebook, compila os arquivos PHP em tempo de execução. Trata-se de uma implementação alternativa do PHP voltada para performance

#### Zephir

Linguágem para se definir funções e classes php compiláveis em C, e as expor através de extensões ao php, basicamente você escreve as classes e funções de forma similar ao PHP (a syntaxe é um pouco diferente) e as compila como uma extensão, um grande exemplo é o framework `phalcon` que é inteiramente compilado e é instalado como extensão a sua intalaç˜åo do PHP

## Segurança

#### IonCube e ZendGuard

Ferramentas proprietárias que criptografam seu código para impedir o fonte de ser lido diretamente (são lidos apenas pela engine dos mesmos instaladas junto a seu php)