# Bloquear código fonte Django

Tags: python, django

Estou desenvolvendo alguns projetos onde irei utilizar [django](/questions/tagged/django), porém vou ter que hospedar o servidor na máquina do cliente. Onde será instalado não tem internet, por isso tenho que fazer o sistema funcionar local.

Preciso saber se de alguma maneira eu consigo proteger o código fonte, para que quando alguém tentar acessar o servidor e pegar os meus arquivos eles estejam de alguma forma "ilegíveis".

Uma vez eu vi que em Asp era possível criar meio que uma DLL do código, em [django](/questions/tagged/django) existem algo parecido ?

Comment: [Como compilar um arquivo PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2487/91)

Comment: Dê uma olhada no PHP Encoder (http://www.ioncube.com/), infelizmente encriptadores opensource não fazem isso muito bem, uma vez que alguns basicamente fazem um `base64_encode` no código. Outra sugestão opensource que vi comentários é o PECL (http://pecl.php.net/package/BLENC), porém não sei algo sobre. Além disso, utilizando os modos legais, você pode fazer um Termo de Uso do seu projeto e um EULA.

Comment: @rray, possível duplicata, hein. Pelo menos em relação ao PHP, já que as respostas iriam pelo mesmo caminho

Comment: Por que toda essa preocupação? rs

Comment: Deixar o código fonte inteiro na máquina do cliente não é algo de muito bom, né ? Tendo ele, alguém pode pegar e ficar usando por aí.

Comment: Então @rray, mas Django é um framework Python e até aonde li da respostas lá, me parecem apenas pra php e não outras linguagem. Votei por deixar em aberto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu sei, teve uma edição que removeu a parte do php :P veja no historico, não votei p fechar. Sobre o python não achei nada tem uma sobre android. Se procurar por ofuscar código já encontra alguns resultados.

Comment: @rray My bad :p - Legal vou procurar algo também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento nem eu tinha visto que parte do php foi removida se vc não deixasse o aviso haha. \o

Comment: Quando você executa um projeto Django ele pega seus arquivos `.py` e gera os compiláveis `.pyc` porque você não tenta subir apenas os arquivos `.pyc` para o ambiente do cliente?

Comment: Na minha visão vc deve fazer isso com um contrato e não no código. E por padrão, a lei determina que um programa de computador por encomenda é propriedade do cliente.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, se a infra não for sua ou de indicação sua, a responsabilidade é do próprio cliente.

Cada arquivo *.py qye você tem, ao ser compilado, ele gera um arquivo *.pyc, que nada mais é que o python compilado.

Essa questão de alguém pegar seu código, envolve muito mais questões de infra estrutura do que programação em si.

São coisas distintas:
 - Segurança do seu servidor;
 - Segurança da sua aplicação (permissões e acesso).

Não cai em ideia de programa que gera dll ou hash do seu código ou sei lá.
O seu código vai estar no servidor e ponto.

O acesso ao servidor irá envolver questões de rede, segurança, quais máquinas podem acessar ao servidor, rede local, rede pública. Existem vários fatores.

Answer (score -3):

Uma boa forma de você alcançar isso pode ser traduzindo seu código para a linguagem C. Além de você torná-lo inelegível seu código irá rodar de uma forma bem mais veloz. Para isso você pode utilizar o [Cython](http://cython.org/).